# What is the best way to retrieve data from a URL protected by credentials in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, reference, file-get-contents

I can retrieve data (JSON) from a route protected by credentials in a Symfony2 project, but for that I use `file_get_contents($url, $include_path, $context)` with `stream_context_create($options)`. Without the context it failed to open the stream.

What's the best way to do this kind of operations? There is some simple Symfony's API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) for this operation. You can check [Guzzle Stream](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#streams) page also.

Comment: The library is cool. By the way I earn like 6 lines of code and the whole code is object-oriented. So I am forced to use this third-party library for this case ? I can't use the Symfony's Client class ? I look the source code and I don't find methods like Guzzle. For instance the `request()` method. (But I notice a `doRequest()` method)